# Segmentation Fault Before main()

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem with this code. After compiling with g++, I run a.out and I get a segmentation fault and no "here" displayed. The code is pretty short:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

bool inWords(vector<string> words, string str);

int main()
{
  cout << "here";

  vector<string> words;
  string str;
  istringstream iss;
  ifstream file("data.txt", ifstream::in);

  // read in words
  for(int i = 0; file >> str; /*no i++*/)
  {
    if(str[str.length() - 1] == '.')
      str.erase( str.length()-1);
      // if word has a period at the end, erase it

    if(!inWords(words, str))
    {
      // if word is not in vector words, add it
      words.push_back(str);
      i++;
    }
  }

  // output each word
  for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
    cout << words[i];

  // return to beginning of file
  file.clear();
  file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

  // read in sentences
  // to be implemented

  file.close();

  return 0;
}

bool inWords(vector<string> words, string str)
{
  for(int i = 0; !words[i].empty(); i++)
    if(words[i] == str) { return true; }
  return false;
}
```

As far as I know, nothing should be a problem. data.txt is definitely in the same directory as the file and I receive no arguments from the command line. Can anyone help?

Comment: The fact that nothing is displayed doesn't imply that the program segfaults before `main()`. It probably just means the program exited without flushing its output buffer.

Comment: You're right. I added and endl after "here", so now I have to find the real source. Thanks

Comment: as a sidenote: always check whether an I/O operation was successfull or not.

Comment: @claptrap: I confess I've never checked a `std::cout <<`, what do you do if it fails?

Comment: @Cramer i was more thinking of file i/o, guess I need to learn to be more specific so that everybody understands, my bad.

Comment: @Lucas: To indicate that a question is solved, please do not edit the title, but put the green checkmark on the answer which solved it for you. In this case there's only one answer so far, but if there's ever a second answer added we won't know anymore which of the two solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be before main. Try using a debugger to see where it happens (eg GDB) which are incredibly handy tool. The reason you don't see "here" is because the buffer isn't flushed. Put a `<< std::endl` after it so that it forces output at that point.

A technicality: You can segfault before main but that will happen in a constructor. I see you have no custom objects defined/instantiated in global scope.

Comment: I really really suggest learning to use a debugger. I give an internet guarantee that your programming life will be 50% more happy. And don't forget to accept ;)

Answer (score 0):

The technique for iterating the vector in `inWords` is wrong and interacts with elements past the end of the vector causing the segmentation fault.

This program immediately accesses `words[0]` in `inWords` when the `words` vector is empty and `words[0]` (the first element of the vector) does not exist yet because the size of the vector is still zero but the loop does not do anything to avoid this condition.

I think `inWords` could be better implemented with `std::find`, perhaps like this:

```
bool inWords(const vector<string>& words, const string& str)
{
  return std::find(words.begin(), words.end(), str) != words.end();
}
```

Remember to `#include <algorithm>` to make use of `std::find`.  I also changed the parameters to pass by const reference, so you'll need to change the forward declaration of that function.  I also added an `endl` to the output to make it readable.

Full text of repair:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool inWords(const vector<string>& words, const string& str);

int main()
{
  vector<string> words;
  string str;
  istringstream iss;
  ifstream file("data.txt", ifstream::in);

  // read in words
  for(int i = 0; file >> str; /*no i++*/)
  {
    if(str[str.length() - 1] == '.')
      str.erase( str.length()-1);
      // if word has a period at the end, erase it

    if(!inWords(words, str))
    {
      // if word is not in vector words, add it
      words.push_back(str);
      i++;
    }
  }

  // output each word
  for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
    cout << words[i] << std::endl;

  // return to beginning of file
  file.clear();
  file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

  // read in sentences
  // to be implemented

  file.close();

  return 0;
}

bool inWords(const vector<string>& words, const string& str)
{
  return std::find(words.begin(), words.end(), str) != words.end();
}
```

Comment: I noticed @SzB woke this from the dead and it seems nobody called out the root cause, so here it is.